# Struggling with IF statement SQL Beginner

Tags: t-sql

```
UPDATE dbo.Contact
SET emailMessenger = '63' WHERE personID = @personID
WHILE (SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE personID = @personID) != @email
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE personID = @personID) IS NULL
        UPDATE Contact SET Email = @personID WHERE personID = @personID
    ELSE IF (SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE personID = @personID) IS NOT NULL
        UPDATE Contact SET SecondaryEmail = email WHERE personID = @personID
        UPDATE Contact SET email = @email WHERE personID = @personID
END
```

What i'm trying to do is add an employees work email to primaryemail. But if they already have a personal email, then I want to first move that to the secondaryemail. But only for the specified employee hence the PersonID.

I've looked at a lot of different examples using CASE and IF-THEN. I think i'm adding too much to the statement. I really thought this Stackoverflow [queston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716671/updating-multiple-columns-using-case-statement-in-sql-server) would help. I know its going to be the syntax or how it's structured.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You just want to clean up your statement a little?

Comment: Show us some example row data before and after.  Its highly unlikely you need a loop construct or if/else.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're doing a loop above this code where you're setting the value of `@personID` and `@email` variables, correct? Can you post the rest of the code? I've pretty sure this can be simplified and a set-based approach can be used, since currently this isn't a very good use of SQL (I'm inclined to say it's actually `T-SQL` / `SQL Server`, isnt' it?)

Comment: I'm sorry my question is I can't this to work it only updates the emailMessenger to 63. I wasn't sure if the the WHILE and IFs were setup correctly. Even as a test I replaced the vars with static @email with 'emp@mail.com' and personID with '1234'

Comment: Yes it is T-SQL. I'm using MS SQL Server Mgmt Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you can do it with an update avoding trigger

```
UPDATE dbo.Contact
SET emailMessenger =  '63',  
    dbo.Contact, 
    SecondaryEmail = CASE when Email is not null then Email else    SecondaryEmail end ,
       Email = CASE when email is null  then 'studentemail.com'
           when email <>'studentemail.com' then 'studentemail.com' else     email end
where personID = '18403';
```

Comment: This looks very good and I like the logic, I knew mine was horrid. I am getting an error though with the SET Email case when email is null then @email. SET says "incorrect syntax near SET expecting CONVERSATION". As does the WHERE on WHERE personID.

Comment: @JoshuaBarrett  this beacuse you are using  sql vars '@email' .. and '@personID'  i aheb update the asnwer with a sample

Comment: UPDATE dbo.Contact
    SET emailMessenger =  '63'
    WHERE personID = '18403'
    UPDATE dbo.Contact
    SET SecondaryEmail = CASE when Email is not null then Email else     SecondaryEmail end 
    WHERE personID = '3'
    UPDATE dbo.Contact
    SET Email = CASE when email is null  then 'myemail@example.com'
                   when email <>'studentemail.com' then     'myemail@example.com' else email end
     WHERE personID = '3'

Comment: @JoshuaBarrett   . i have update the answer with a correct version and one update only .. thanks anyway ..

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following your logic correctly, the following should do the trick.

I first set up a testing table with all possible problem permutations (email present in one, both, or neither column). If your data doesn't look something like this, my solution may not apply.

```
drop table Contact

CREATE TABLE Contact
 (
   PersonId        int           not null
  ,Email           varchar(100)  null
  ,SecondaryEmail  varchar(100)  null
 )

INSERT Contact values
  (1, null, null)
 ,(2, 'OnlyFirst', null)
 ,(3, null, 'OnlySecond')
 ,(4, 'FirstEmail', 'SecondEmail')
```

And the following to set the change to make, show contents before, make the change, then show contents after.

```
DECLARE
  @PersonId  int
 ,@Email     varchar(100) = 'NewEmail@foo.com'

SET @PersonId = 4

--  Before
SELECT * from Contact

--  Modify
UPDATE Contact
 set
   Email          = @Email
  ,SecondaryEmail = case when Email is not null then Email else SecondaryEmail end
 where PersonID = @PersonID

--  After
SELECT * from Contact
```

Net result: @Email is always set in column Email, and @SecondaryEmail is set to the contents of Email only if Email was not null

Comment: And you can add `,emailMessenger = 63` to the Update statement, though presumably it too should be a parameter (?)